# How to disable background blur effect on macOS Sierra login screen

Tags: macos, login-screen

I've replaced /Library/Desktop Pictures/Sierra.jpg with a custom background image. Now, macOS Sierra applies the blur effect on my custom background image as well. I am looking for a reliable solution to turn it off e.g. overwriting a plist preference file or any non-hacking workaround?

How can I completely disable the login screen background blur and show a crystal clear login image?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

1. Go to /Library/Caches/
2. Rename the original com.apple.desktop.admin.png file to com.apple.desktop.admin1.png
3. Add a new image in its place with the original *com.apple.desktop.admin.png* name

This will replace the blurred original image with the new one unblurred.

Comment: yeah, this workflow applies to El Capitan and Yosemite. It doesn't work with macOS Sierra. I've replaced /Library/Caches/com.apple.desktop.admin.png. As soon as restart or logout the image is still blurred.

Comment: Did you rename the original file and then add a new one? Or did you just replace the original?

Comment: a) I have renamed com.apple.desktop.admin.png to com.apple.desktop.admin1.png. b) Than I copied my custom image and replace it with com.apple.desktop.admin.png. c) Logout + System reboot

Comment: That's interesting. I know these steps worked in macOS Sierra. I wonder if the actual image itself has an effect somehow? When I get a chance I will try a few different ones and test the results.

Comment: I'd confirm that this does in fact work with macOS Sierra, but it seems unnecessary that you suggested in your answer to create a backup of the original blurred image - you wouldn't need it again if you are replacing it anyways.

Comment: I've tried these steps with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and it is not working. I even tried reboot and that didn't make it work as well. Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Turn on "Reduce Transparency" in Accessibility and it will remove the blur effect.

[image]

This used to be called "Translucency" before, but for some reason they changed it to "Transparency".

I just tested it and my blurred login screen went to a simple grey screen.

Comment: Unfortunately "Reduce Transparency" doesn't remove the blurred background image. The Background image with our company logo is still blurred. With solid plain color backgrounds you might not see any difference.

Comment: I don't any have solid color backgrounds... I will look a bit more into it.

Answer (score -2):

i've found this somewhere :

The file in /System/Library/CoreServices/DefaultDesktop.jpg is an alias that points to /Library/Desktop Pictures/Sierra.jpg.

so i changed the picture called "Sierra.jpg" by mine & i get this picture in login window.
but it still blur effect. 
i do not know how to remove it !

another page here, but i can not understand anything !
https://onemoreadmin.wordpress.com/2016/09/24/apples-efi-logonui-managing-macos-sierras-wallpaper/

Comment: Making modifications to the System folder is not recommended! As I mentioned above, replacing the desktop image is working just fine. however I would like to disable the background blur.

Comment: same for me,, i've just mentioned this because it could be a way of investigation...